# API URI format for handling AND and OR logic following RFC 6570

Tags: rest, crud, rfc

I am currently building a Crud based Rest API that uses query strings to refine a search.

For instance the following would return all blue cars that are sedans **AND** have 4 doors:

```
/cars?color=blue&type=sedan&doors=4
```

What would be the correct approach to structure a query to check for all cars that are blue **OR** are sedans **OR** have 4 doors?

This is probably incorrect, but I imagine it will demonstrate what I am trying to do:

```
/cars?color=blue|type=sedan|doors=4
```

Is it even proper to manipulate the type of operation carried out by the API with the delimiter between these fields, to treat the url more like a database query? If it is, how do you handle nested operations, like getting a car that or blue **OR** a car that that is a sedan **AND** has 4 doors.

For instance something like this:

```
/cars?color=blue|(type=sedan&doors=4)
```

I am trying to follow [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), but have not seen any mention of doing anything like this.

Thanks!

Comment: in the url `&` does not mean "and", it's just the separator for each set of `key`=`value`. you are giving it the meaning of and.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the correct approach to structure a query to check for all cars that are blue OR are sedans OR have 4 doors?

The usual answer would be to use identifiers with a different path

- `/theOneWithTheAnd?color=blue&type=sedan&doors=4`
- `/theOneWithTheOr?color=blue&type=sedan&doors=4`

If you were to imagine this on the web, it would probably look like two different forms, possibly with the same input fields, but with different form.action.

---

Expressed as an RFC 6570 level one template, you would have something like

- `/theOneWithTheAnd?color={color}&type={type}&doors={doors}`
- `/theOneWithTheOr?color={color}&type={type}&doors={doors}`

You could, of course, express a path segment of the identifier as a template parameter as well

- `/{reportName}?color={color}&type={type}&doors={doors}`

With a level two template, you could span multiple path segments

- `{+reportName}?color={color}&type={type}&doors={doors}`

With a level three template, you can simplify the description of the query part

- `{+reportName}{?color,type, doors}`

---

Using key value pairs is convenient (we have a many tools that already know how to do that work), but not required.  You could just as easily encode a sql query into the identifier

`/reports?select%20*%20from%20students;`

URI templates still work

`/reports?select%20*%20from%20students%20where%20id={id};`

From the perspective of REST, it is still just an identifier; there's no fundamental difference between that identifier spelling and a more mundate

`/8721ccc6-75e0-4da3-93f4-7f9dc9d4cfd9`

Mom will of course remind you that you shouldn't [blindly copy information](https://xkcd.com/327/) from the HTTP request to the queries you apply to your production database, but that's an orthogonal concern to the question of how we identify a particular document (resource).

Comment: So doing something like encoding and SQL statement in a uri would not be something I would want to do for security reasons as you noted. But I am looking to do something that supports AND, OR, LIKE, IN, CONCAT like functionality being executed from the front end. I would probably create some sort of JSON object format to pass back and parse as part of the query string. We have similar custom code running datatables in our system. Is that an ok practice for writing API's? My Vue dev would like to to change his API queries to the back end as he needs with no change in API code.